# Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space. Then $(X,d)$ is both complete and bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification, cauchy-sequences

> Definition: A metric space $(X,d)$ is said to be compact iff every sequence admits a convergent subsequence.

I am having trouble with the following result:

> Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space. Then $(X,d)$ is both complete and bounded.

So far I have been able to prove that $(X,d)$ is complete as follows.

If $X$ is compact, then every sequence $x_{n}\in X$ admits a convergent subsequence.

In particular, if $x_{n}$ is Cauchy, then it admits a convergence subsequence, which makes it convergent as well.

What concerns me is the second part. How do we prove that it is bounded?

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is not bounded there exist $x_n,y_n$ such that $d(x_n,y_n) \to \infty$. There exist subsequences $x_{n_k}$ and $y_{n_k}$ converging to some points $x$ and $y$. Can you show using triangle inequality that $d(x,y)=\lim d(x_{n_k},y_{n_k}$)? That would lead to the contradiction $d(x,y)=\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \in X$ and $B_1{x}$ an open  ball around $x$ with radius $1$ with respect the metric $d$. Obviously, $X= \cup_{x \in X}B_1(x)$. As $X$ is compact, $X$ is covered by a finite union $B_1(x_1) \cup ... \cup B_1(x_n)$. Each $B_1(x_i)$ is bounded and a finite union of bounded sets is also bounded.